# Rest API show items if current log in user equal me

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, person-or-group

I have two user column in SharePoint 2013 RequestedFor and CC. I want to display items only if the user in either column is equal current log in user.

So far I'm able to display items when Requested for is equal to log in user.  I want to show items if the user is part of RequestedFor or CC field.

```
var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;function loadListItems(){var oDataUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SupportList')/items?$select=ID,Created,Modified,Title,Status,RequestType,RequestedFor/Title,CC/Title&$expand=CC,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=RequestedFor,AssignedTo&$filter=RequestedFor eq " + userId;
console.log(_spPageContextInfo);
$.ajax(
{url: oDataUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers:
    {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successFunction,
    error: errorFunction
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your REST API endpoint similar to this:

```
"$select=Title,RequestedFor/ID,CC/ID&$expand=RequestedFor,CC&$filter=(RequestedFor/ID eq " + userId + " or CC/ID eq " + userId + ")";
```

Comment: Thank you this works!